# RichTextBox line break after n characters

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Is there a way to break the line in a `RichTextBox` after a specific amount of characters without the string having a new line? (In this example case `5` characters but in my real code after `80` characters)

```
//Rendered as
Examp 
le Te
xt  

//Actual String
Console.WriteLine(richTextBox1.Text) //"Example Text"
```

I am highlighting a specific phrase in a it.
For example `"Text"` is being highlighted and it only works if the string is `"Example Text"` and not `"Examp\nle Te\nxt"`

I've also tried Replacing `"\n"` with `""` and then readjusting the positions because `'\n'` counts as a character but I could not get it to work

Comment: Are you sure it's not "\r\n"? Since you're on Windows and that's the correct way to have new-lines on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "\n" try replacing Enviroment.NewLine with "" and then readjusting the positions.

```
string Text = richTextBox1.Text;
Text = Text.Replace(Enviroment.NewLine, "");

string NewText = "";
for(int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++){

    if( i % 5 == 0)// Insert a line break every 5 characters
        NewText += Enviroment.NewLine;

    NewText += Text[i];
}
```

If you need maxium performance you may want to use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) or take a look into [String.Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx)